# Increase and decrease font size in DevExpress gridview using mouse

Tags: c#, events, gridview, devexpress

I'm trying to increase decrease the size of the font in the cells of a DevExpress GridView. I know that the event is probably

```
private void gridView1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {}
```

Does anyone have experience implementing this functionality?

I've looked around on Google and found this: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q20861.aspx

But when I add this code to my solution I get errors about Point, GridView, and Font missing references and using directives.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to see if you have the latests dlls, perhaps the version you have is not updated. Usually when references are missing when you instantiate, you would get a small redish underscore that may suggest to include it. If not then you need to find the dll and add it as a reference in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you mentioned from the [page](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q20861.aspx) i made a small modification and it works for me.

```
GridView v = sender as GridView;
```

For GridView you have to add this,

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;
```

With this code you won't need to use mouse location using `Point` class

Comment: Thanks for this. I just neeed to add 'using System.Drawing;' to get rid of errors with Font.

Answer (score 0):

in properties click on the Columns property and if it has column,db-click on the column`s name and select`CellStyle`and change`Font`property such you can change`HeaderStyle` and so on